# Algebra question involving quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I dont know how to approach this problem. I tried considering letting w be a common root then I substituted into both equations and equate them and I get into (a-b)(w-1)=0 but what does that exactly means in the context of the problem and are these all the solutions?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. If $w$ is the common root, then
$$
w^2+aw+b=0,\qquad w^2+bw+a=0
$$
and subtracting the two equations yields
$$
(a-b)w+b-a=0
$$
hence
$$
(a-b)(w-1)=0
$$
What does this mean? Well, it can be $a=b$ and so the original equations are the same, so they have common roots.

Otherwise the common root is $1$, so we need $1^2+a\cdot1+b=0$ and the condition becomes $b=-a-1$.

Hence the only cases when the equations have common roots are $b=a$ or $b=-a-1$.

If you need the roots to be real, the first case requires  $a^2-4b\ge0$, that is $a^2-4a\ge0$, and therefore $a\le0$ or $a\ge4$.

In the second case we don't need to compute the discriminant, because the equations do have at least a real root, so both roots are real (assuming $a,b$ are real).